# Verbs and pronouns in action phrases e.g. me: *smiles*

Tags: grammar, slang, colloquialisms

An action is usually a verb phrase surrounded in asterisks to show that someone is doing something. When an action is written, why is it using the third person verb conjugation even though the subject is in the first or second person? It doesn't feel right if I use the first or second person verb conjugation. I know that it can also use the gerund form of the verb. But the gerund can be used with any subject.

For example:

> me: *smiles* (common)

> me: *smile* (doesn't feel right)

It's quite commonly used in memes. [Example](https://twitter.com/NYC_Blonde/status/1082265298563203074)

It's also found in texting while performing an action or role-playing.

> *blushes*

Other examples can be found by searching 'role play texting' on Google Images.

And also why does it use the object form of the pronouns and not the subject form? It also doesn't feel right if I use the subject form of the pronoun,

Example:

> me: *smiles*

> I: *smiles*

Why is that the case? Has it been this way since a long time ago or is it only done now because of the internet?

Comment: It's almost certainly a deleted comment clause:  {dialogue} ... [the actor] smiles // {dialogue} ... [the actors] exeunt, pursued by a bear.

Comment: But why does it use the third-person verb conjugation even though the subject is in first person?

Comment: They are also nouns. Me: smiles. Other: blushes.

Comment: I agree with Edwin Ashworth: the [smiles], usually in square brackets, is basically a stage direction - these are added to the line in a play to indicate to the character speaking or involved what action should be done. See http://image.slidesharecdn.com/playscripts-teacheraswriter-130227164952-phpapp02/95/play-scripts-teacher-as-writer-28-638.jpg%3Fcb%3D1361983863

Comment: It looks to me like an imitation of a stage direction. _John: Where are you, Mary? (Sees her lying on ground) What's happened? Are you hurt? (Kneels beside her) etc. etc.

Comment: Are you all saying that it evolves from stage directions?

Comment: @Kate - What happens next? _I need to know!_

Comment: Mary (slurs words) Man, I'm shitfaced! That vodka sure is good. John: (sombrely) I am most upset to see you like this, Mary, I thought you were a fine, upstanding church member. Mary (loudly) Shaddap and gemme a drink!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ***stage directions*** (and facetious imitations thereof) don't really have "grammar" or "syntax".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These "asterisk-bounded autonomous stage directions" are a mashup of traditional playwright conventions and modern internet ones.

Like traditional stage directions, they exist outside of the characters' first-person dialogue and are therefore in the third person. They also display the brevity of phrasing, unique typographic demarcation, and "viral-ness" that the internet craves.

In [The cyberpragmatics of bounding asterisks](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4466), Language Log's Ben Zimmer summarizes:

> . . . by giving yourself your own stage directions enclosed in
> asterisks, you treat your own words as lines in a play, and then step
> outside of your character to give the perspective of the playwright in
> the play you're acting in.

As for the origins, Mr. Zimmer explores "the use of bounding asterisks to signal non-verbal noises or actions as a kind of self-describing stage direction." He points to comic strip caligraphy as an influence, and notes that:

> The origins of such usage likely can be found in text-based
> role-playing games in MUDs (Multi-User Dungeons/Domains), which were
> superseded by IRC and instant-messaging interfaces. As one "Role Play
> Manual of Style" explains, "Actions are enclosed in asterisks and
> written in third person perspective." But this type of asterisking has
> thoroughly infected Usenet posts, blog comments, tweets, and anywhere
> else online that people feel the need to describe real-world actions
> in a virtual space.

As for the use of *me* instead of *I*, forget about subject and object personal pronouns and instead think of *me* as a name—a proper noun—that you call yourself.

<sub>References:

[The cyberpragmatics of bounding asterisks](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4466)

[Asterisks > Computing > Computer Interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk#Computer_interfaces)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I always assumed that the whole

> /me smiles

with or without asterisks came from chatrooms where a "/me" or something similar was rendered as {nickname} {does something}.

So I would type */me smiles* and in the chat it would show as

> *oerkelens* smiles

In that case it doesn't make sense to use the first person singular.

In many places these habits have survived (and are even picked up by people that never knew the use of them in the first place).
I still catch myself using */me* like this even when it just shows as /me, just like I still tend to type simplified emoticons like 8)7 or |:( even in places where they don't get rendered the way they do on a forum where I used to be very active.

Disregarding the /me -> nickname -> we need a 3rd person singular verb, there may be older cases of *me* in combination with a verb. The (now archaic?) construct *methinks* is one, and seems to be constructed treating *me* as a third person singular rather than first. Possibly because the speaker *describes* the action as if talking about a third party.

Comment: So it's simply a habit from old chatrooms? It's funny and fascinating how language can be spread that quickly. And when it doesn't feel right, that's because it's never been used, right?

Comment: I have not encountered it _before_ those chat rooms, but I cannot proof its origins. It doesn't seem all too implausible to me, though. That new things can spread quickly is nothing new: look at the use of emoticons :) About the last remark, "NickJohn smile" feels wrong, not because it hasn't been done before but because the (nick)name requires a third person singular verb.

Comment: It sounds as though the chatroom usage may have derived from the play script usage.